# Opencart Undefined index: name in /vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php on line 103

Tags: opencart

I am having trouble with an error code that I am getting in Opencart 1.5.4. My client gets it on a lot of pages and it causes them to load without the CSS file (which give them just lines of text with almost no styling).

The site is: http://garrysun.com/

The error shows up on some product pages and the error is:

```
Undefined index: name in /vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php on line 103
```

Line 103 is the part about manufacturer_id below in this part of thecode:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

  $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

...

```
if ($product_info) {
       $url = '';if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
       $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
    }
```

If you need more of the code let me know but basically it is in the section about

I am not sure what is causing it because I can't reproduce the problem on my computer. They are using Internet Explorer 11.

This page has the error in Chrome but it doesn't cause the page to lose its stylesheet: https://garrysun.com/soaps-skin-care?product_id=222

Does anyone know what is causing this problem. I have various extensions installed but don't know if any of them are causing the problems.

Please let me know if you can help.

EDIT:

These are pages that the client has said that there are errors when using IE 11

https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories/bulk-herbs?product_id=72

https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories/bulk-herbs?product_id=79

https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories/bulk-herbs?product_id=71

Here are some pages with the error at the top.

ONLY 1 ERROR

https://garrysun.com/herbal-teas?product_id=107

TWO ERRORS:

https://garrysun.com/777-oil

https://garrysun.com/psorolin_ointment

https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories/herbal-tablets?product_id=102

https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories/soaps-skin-care?product_id=222

Comment: Can you please tell whether you copied the line 103 of `/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php` or the line 103 of `catalog/controller/product/product.php`? We need the line  103 of `/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php`.

Comment: That was line 103 from the vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php

Comment: After checking I realized that they are exactly the same line of code. Not sure what the the vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php file does.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution but I just went into Admin->System->Settings->[edit your configured store]->Server->Display Errors and turned off display errors and the site started working correctly. Guess IE 11 doesn't like displaying the errors. If anyone knows how to fix the name error I would appreciate it but if not the site should be working correctly now.